# error in ensemble PLSR (Partial Least Square Regression) code

Tags: python

https://github.com/pgbrodrick/ensemblePLSR.

I have downloaded python code and sample data from the link mentioned above.
I am novice in programming/coding. while running the code, I am getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\SOME_PATH\ensemble_plsr.py", line 167, in 
>       sf = read_settings_file.settings(sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5rkL.png)) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the first (167) line of the main code is

`sf = read_settings_file.settings(sys.argv[1])`
you need to provide the location of the settings file when running the program, when you not providing sys args the main get an empty array `sys.arg=[]` but try to access index 1 thus result in index out of range

try to run

`python ensemble_plsr.py example_settings.txt`

I'm assuming the settings file is in the same dir as the main program

Comment: yes. both files are in same dir. as the main program

Comment: @MaulikDave sry, paste the wrong file, try with `example_settings.txt`